# Why I get NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php?

Tags: php, laravel-5

As I have deployed my app to the server, `default/storage/framework/views` is empty, how would I generate them at the server side?

Being empty, would this result into the error of `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php?` as I get this into the browser:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
in RouteCollection.php line 145
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Although I have all the routes working, I've detected them using

> php artisan route:list

How would investigate the issue?

Comment: Did you upload all the files to the server, outside the `public_html` or `www` directory in your hosting account ?

Comment: yes, I just did, I still get the same error